# String representation for data loaded via fixture in Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm using Django 1.6 and loading some initial data via a JSON fixture.
eg.

```
{
    "model": "myapp.field",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "name": "ABC 100"
    }
}
```

How do I specify the string representation that I wan't to use for these fields on the Django admin page?  At the moment, my dropdown menu defaults to showing "Abc 100".  Is there a way to change this?

**EDIT:**

I am aware that you define the string representation via the `__unicode__` method, and also that you can explicitly define them using choices.  I was wondering whether there was a way to define the string representations explicitly (like with using choices) but with fixtures.  So that the definition isn't hardcoded in my models.py file.

Comment: have you tried pytest?  I was looking into pytest based on your response and generating fixtures through it.  It might be worth looking into because it sounds like it addresses this and would be the fix you need.

Answer (score 1):

You would define the string representation that shows in your `admin.py` page in your `models.py` using the `__unicode__` argument.  Here is a simple code example:

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

You can concatenate strings, add other functions, etc... to the `__unicode__` function.  Anything that you can do in normal python.

If you want to define a list of choices within a field as a dropdown, you would want to use code like this to limit the choices:

```
# product contrast choices
DARK = 'Dark'
LIGHT = 'Light'
CONTRAST_CHOICES = (
    (DARK, 'Dark'),
    (LIGHT, 'Light'),
    )
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  contrast = models.CharField(_("Contrast"), max_length=25, choices=CONTRAST_CHOICES, blank=True)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I should have been more explicit.  I was aware of these two options.  I was wondering whether there was a way to define the string representations explicitly (like with using choices) but with fixtures.  So that the definition isn't hardcoded in my models.py file.